# C# Get information from database

Tags: c#, mysql

Searched around and cant seem to find somebody who has answered this..

I have a 'Service-Based Database' set up with a table that contains the members of an organization I am in. I want to be able to display a groupbox that has a list of all the members. (I am thinking I need to somehow use the foreach command and then say for each line in the table insert a label, but idk)

I want the groupbox to have a list of all the members' names(By getting the MemberName column in the database) and then when you click on the members name, it opens up a box with all the users info.

I have:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = .; Initial Catalog = domain; Integrated Security = True"); 
con.Open(); 
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from table", con);
```

for my connection and then I am trying to do

```
foreach (Select MemberName from table) 
{ Controls.Add(Label); Label.Text = memberName;}
```

But it is not adding a label for each member in the database.

Any help on how to accomplish this?

Comment: You should really try something and ask questions when you are stuck

Comment: I have `SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = .; Initial Catalog = domain; Integrated Security = True");
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from table", con);` for my connection and then I am trying to do `foreach (Select MemberName from table) {     Controls.Add(Label);
    Label.Text = memberName;}`, but it is not adding a label for each member in the database.

Comment: @Cody_T Add this code to your original question

Comment: It is not common to add select results as labels. Maybe a Listbox or datagridview would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not creating a new instance of the label.
In your for loop, create a new instance, add it to the controls and then set the text.

EDIT: You are also having issues w/ your reader.  Try executing the query, then loop through the reader.  Here, reader[0] assumes that memberName is your first column.

```
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        var memberName = reader[0].ToString();
        var lbl = new Label();
        Controls.Add(lbl); 
        lbl.Text = memberName;
    }
```

Comment: It is showing that `foreach (Select MemberName from table) ` is an error. That's what I don't understand.

Comment: yes.. i just realized your syntax error.  one moment and i'll try to get it fixed.

Comment: "The name 'results' does not exist in the current context."

Comment: @Cody_T Try that, let me know if i've missed anything.

Comment: in the `lbl.Text = memberName;` it is saying that "Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exist. (Are you missing a cast?)". It is referring to the memberName

Comment: @Cody_T That'd be a tostring on the end of the reader.

Comment: It looks like your code will work. But I am having connection problems :( the connection before wouldn't work, im using `SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=.\\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Cody\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\ExplorerManagement\\ExplorerManagement\\bin\\Debug\\Database1.mdf;Database=dbo; Trusted_Connection=Yes;");` now, and it also doesn't work and I dont know why.

Comment: @Cody_T .mdf?!?!  you tagged this as a mysql question.  I would NOT recommend going straight to the file.  Rather go to [ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) and look for help to use the correct connection string.